# Звідки взялося слово "пішак" в українській мові?

Tags: етимологія

Ось які назви шахматних фігур дає [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8)):

- [король](http://sum.in.ua/s/korolj)
- [ферзь](http://sum.in.ua/s/ferzj)
- [тура](http://sum.in.ua/s/tura)
- [слон](http://sum.in.ua/s/slon)
- [кінь](http://sum.in.ua/s/kinj)
- [пішак](http://sum.in.ua/s/pishak)

Як бачимо, всі ці слова є в СУМі. Як виявилося ферзь - це [запозичення з турецької](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/978-966-00-0197-8/978-966-00-0197-8.pdf) (див. ст. 89), тура - [з фарцузької](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2006/EtSlUkrM_2006.pdf) (див. ст. 678).

Однак в ЕСУмі немає ніякої інформації про слово "[пішак](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf)". То чи може це бути запозичення з [російської](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B)? Чи це звичайне українське слово?

Comment: Чому? Все је – шукајте в словіі [_пішиј_](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_2003/EtSlUkrM_2003.pdf#page=420). Ось шче на [додачу](https://i.imgur.com/e0tDlyf.png).

Comment: То виходить слово походить від назви земельної одиниці міри?

Comment: Ньі, від слова [тс.] — так само, сьебто _піхотинець_.

Comment: Тобто виходить, що все таки не запозичене слово? А ще, що схожі варіанти є і у інших слов'янських мовах.

Comment: Саме слово не запозичене, а спосіб вживу калькованиј, однак, јак видно, не обовјазково з московськојі. Тому бажано вточнити питанье. Також про всьак зазначу, шчо імена постатеј бувајуть ріжними, особливо в розмовному. Сьебто "ферзь" мо’ бути "королева", "слон" — "офіцер", "тура" — "ладдье", і дальі.